# Inserting object properties into text fields based on drop down menu selection

Tags: javascript, text, drop-down-menu

I have recently started using javascript and perhaps got a little in over my head. I'm trying to create a tool for one of my other hobbies that creates coordinates for fences from x1,y1 to x2,y2.

The part that I am getting hung up on right now is part of the UI. I want the user to be able to select their desired fence from a dropdown menu and then for the rest of the information pertaining to the fence (name, length, width, direction, etc.) to be filled into the input fields below. From there they will be referenced in the math portion which I already have done.

I want the fence pieces to be objects because I'm going to add more eventually and perhaps allow the user to add more and I figured that was the easiest more user friendly way to go about it.

I have managed to get to the point where the options are in the dropdown menu, I can select them, and it will fill the piece name in with the value which is the name but I cannot figure out how to access the length, width, height, etc.

This is my first project outside of Code Academy and a little bit I did 10 years ago in High School. That being said, if you notice that I am doing something else stupid, feel free to point it out. The answers for other's questions here have already been a huge source of help for me as I worked on this, so thank you for that and for the future help.

```
<script>
        //Start Variable Library
            var dropMenuPieceName =  0;
            var dropMenuPieceName =  0;
        //End Variable Library
        // Start Function Library

            var fencePieceDropDown = function(dropDownMenuID) {

                var dropMenu = document.getElementById(dropDownMenuID); 
                for(var i = 0; i < fenceArray.length; i++) {
                    var dropMenuOption = document.createElement("option");
                    var dropMenuPieceName =  fenceArray[i].name;
                    var dropMenuPieceName =  fenceArray[i].length;
                    dropMenuOption.innerHTML = fenceArray[i].model;
                    dropMenuOption.value = fenceArray[i].name;
                    var dropMenuIndex = 1;
                    dropMenu.add(dropMenuOption,dropMenuIndex);
                };
            };
        //End Function Library
        // Start Fence Object Library

            function Fence(name,model,length,width,direction,x_offSet,y_offSet,z_offSet,r_offSet) {
                this.name = name;
                this.model = model;
                this.length = length;
                this.width = width;
                this.direction = direction;
                this.x_offSet = x_offSet;
                this.y_offSet = y_offSet;
                this.z_offSet = z_offSet;
                this.r_offSet = r_offSet;
            };

            var fenceArray = new Array();

            var plot_ohrada = new Fence
                ("plot_ohrada","plot_ohrada",3,0.1,0.02,0,0,0,0);
            fenceArray[0] = plot_ohrada;

            var plot_ohrada_pruchozi = new Fence
                ("plot_ohrada_pruchozi","plot_ohrada_pruchozi",4,0.2,0.02,0,0,0,0);
            fenceArray[1] = plot_ohrada_pruchozi;

            var plot_ohrada_zlomena = new Fence
                ("plot_ohrada_zlomena","plot_ohrada_zlomena",5,0.3,0.03,0,0,0,0);
            fenceArray[2] = plot_ohrada_zlomena;

        //End Fence Object Library
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="primPieceSection">
        <div align="center">
            Piece Model:
            <select id="primPieceModel" >
                <option value = 0>Custom Piece</option>
            <select><br /><br /><br />
            Piece Name: <input  type="text" id="primPieceName" placeholder="Insert Template Name"><br />
            Piece Length: <input type="text" id="primPieceLength" value=0><br />
            Piece Width: <input type="text" id="primPieceWidth" value=0><br />
            Piece Direction: <input type="text" id="primPieceDir" value=0><br />
        </div>
    </form>
<script>
    var primPieceNameField = document.getElementById("primPieceName");
    var primPieceLengthField = document.getElementById("primPieceLength");
    var primPieceModelDrop = document.getElementById("primPieceModel");

    primPieceModelDrop.onchange = function() {
        primPieceNameField.value = this.value; ///this should return the object's name
        primPieceLengthField.value = this.value; ///this should return the object's length. I just put in this.value while I was testing it.
    };  

    fencePieceDropDown("primPieceModel");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the `value` of each dropdown option should be not its name, but rather the index of the corresponding fence in the `fenceArray`, which is `i`. Then, inside `primPieceModelDrop.onchange`, you will use `fenceArray[this.value]` to access the selected fence object.

So, you need to replace this line:

```
dropMenuOption.value = fenceArray[i].name;
```

with this:

```
dropMenuOption.value = i;
```

And then rewrite the `onchange` handler as follows:

```
primPieceModelDrop.onchange = function() {
    primPieceNameField.value = fenceArray[this.value].name;
    primPieceLengthField.value = fenceArray[this.value].length;
};
```

What you’re doing is perfectly reasonable for a beginner, but you should understand that it’s a somewhat simplistic, low-level approach. As you become more confident in JS, and as your project grows, you may find it easier to employ a framework such as [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/).

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to get to work so I didn't have much time to check it but in my quick check it seems to be doing exactly what I need it to do. Thank you.